# iptables password protection followup

Tags: iptables

This is a follow up on my other post about this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48055/iptables-plaintext-password-protection
I could not get help in the old topic...I just really need some help...

Here is the command I tried, something it wrong with it. How do I enter this command? This is for educational purpose only. Say, if I use "password" for all my logins.

Thanks!

nata@nata-VirtualBox:~$ **iptables -A OUTPUT -s match --string "password" --dport 80 -p tcp -j DROP** iptables v1.4.12: unknown option "--string" Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

nata@nata-VirtualBox:~$ **iptables -A OUTPUT -m string --string "password" --dport 80 -p tcp -j DROP** string: Could not determine whether revision 1 is supported, assuming it is. iptables v1.4.12: unknown option "--dport" Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Also did this: nata@nata-VirtualBox:~$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp  -m string  --algo bm --string "password" --dport 80 -j DROP
There is no error, but the page login works with the password.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some odd groups of parameters, where you mix the different matching modules and protocols. I.e. --dport 80 does not make sense before it sees the -p tcp parameters.

I have not the possibility to test here, but I believe this should do it:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string 'password' -j DROP
```

[This](http://spamcleaner.org/en/misc/w00tw00t.html) page provides a great tutorial on how to do similar things: